# HQL Inner join on same table

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I asked an earlier question today which was about GORM: [How to fetch records in grails by max date and group at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484883/how-to-fetch-records-in-grails-by-max-date-and-group-at-same-time)  However, someone suggested it can be easily achieved using HQL. But using HQL I'm getting `unexpected token` error. When I researched this I found out that HQL doesn't allow `INNER JOINS` unless there is an association between two entities: [HQL, left join on the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741439/hql-left-join-on-the-same-table)

So, I'm lost. To begin with, I'm frustrated why such a simple query isn't supported by GORM and now with HQL my question is: How do I perform an INNER JOIN on a subset?

What I've tried:

> unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 16 [ select c from ( select
>   name, max(dateCreated) as maxTime from com.mine.Color
>   group by name ) as t inner join Color c on c.name = t.name and
>   c.dateCreated = t.maxTime ]

I suspected that the second instance of `Color` was not being detected since the package name didn't get automatically prefixed to it. So reading other answers I tried:

> unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 16 [ select c from ( select
>   name, max(dateCreated) as maxTime from com.mine.Color
>   group by name ) as t , com.mine.Color as c on c.name =
>   t.name and c.dateCreated = t.maxTime ]

Comment: I think I have something for you, hold on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Color.executeQuery("""    
    Select c
    From Color c
    where c.dateCreated = (select max(b.dateCreated) from Color b where b.name = c.name)
    """)
```

Comment: This works !! - Can you shed some light on what is different? other than putting the subquery in the where clause rather than from? Whats the underlying thing that makes these two queries different from HQL perspective.

Comment: Well your query returns records and mine just returns a single value, so possibly HQL is better equipped to handle it. I'm not really sure